# Drop where I release my finger

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I made a drag and drop system, but when I insert the item, it looks like gravity is top, when inserting new ones, they stay on top of each other, how do I drop where I let go of my finger?

The items are in a list, I get them like this:

```
public void criarListagem(List<croquiA> cro) {
        CroquiAdapter adapter = new CroquiAdapter(cro, this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setDivider(null);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            arrayClass.p = arrayClass.pistasIds[position];
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("simple_text", "text");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            newClick(arrayClass.p, l);

            if(l != 0){
                findViewById(R.id.container).setOnDragListener(new MyOnDragListener());
            }

            return false;
        });
```

MyOnDragListener:

```
class MyOnDragListener implements View.OnDragListener{

        public MyOnDragListener(){
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();

            switch (action){
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                   if(event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)){
                       return true;
                   }else{
                       return false;
                   }

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;

                    //Here I copy to the view and add an ImageView 
                    //instead of remove because it is an adapter, so it is 
                    //not possible to remove it

                    ImageView oldView = (ImageView) view;
                    ImageView newView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                    newView.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) oldView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());

                    container.addView(newView);

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    break;

            }

            return true;
        }
```

When I drop it looks like this:

[image]

In that I made 2 drops, realize that one image is on top of the other and they are not created where I let go of the finger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MyOnDragListener you need to specify the position, where to drop the new View into your layout. Try the following: Change this line

```
container.addView(newView);
```

into

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - oldView.getWidth()/2;
params.topMargin = (int) event.getY() - oldView.getHeight()/2;

container.addView(newView, params);
```

Comment: Dude, you're a genius !!! would it be possible to add the drag n drop event to these new created images as well?

Comment: I would say so. Just try `newView.setOnDragListener(new MyOnDragListener())`

Comment: In fact it looks like this:
     `newView.setOnLongClickListener(vi -> {
                        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("simple_text", "text");
                        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(vi);
                        vi.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, vi, 0);
                        vi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return true;
                    });`

Comment: But now I know you can add events to new things created, thank you

Comment: Happy to help :D